# Java библиотека для нахождение произовдной от функции.

Tags: java, math

Кто нибудь знает подобную библиотеку?

Comment: можно использовать matlab + обертка на java.

А в принципе, для небольшого класса функций можно и самому написать.

Comment: Ну конечно, Java можно использовать в т.ч. для того, чтобы заколачивать им гвозди, но все таки я полагаю проще обратиться к спец.пакетам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще написать самому